# How do I allow anonymous access to just one controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using MVC 2.0 with forms authentication. I want to allow public access to one controller called "Logout". Currently whenever I browse to it I get bounced to Login.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login/Login"  
         protection="All" timeout="30"
         name=".ASPXAUTH" 
         path="/" 
         requireSSL="false" 
         slidingExpiration="true"
         defaultUrl="Token/Create" 
         cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" 
         enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
</authentication>

<!-- Deny Anonymous users. -->
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

---

**Update:** I am using WIF and each time the user arrives at the registration page (anonymous access) I need to sign them out, to ensure that they have the latest claims in their token, and are not just allowed in with a stale token. Their claims are coming in via the request to the registration page.

Comment: Huh? Why should non-logged-in users be able to log out?

Comment: it does sound a bit strange i know!  i am using w.i.f and each time the user arrives at the registration page (anon access) i need to sign them out, to ensure that they have the latest claims in their token, and are not just allowed in with a stale token.  Their claims are coming in via the request to the registration page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As SLaks mentioned, there should be no need for a non-logged-in user to access the Logout action. But, if you want to enable anonymous access to controllers / actions you have to enable it in your Web.Config:

```
<location path="~/Logout">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

A better approach for a pure MVC app is to use the `Authorize` attribute and enable access to all users in the web.config.

Comment: thanks. the reason i need a non logged in user to access logout, is because they are coming from an anon access page, but need sign out, so that i can create them new security token with fresh claims. its a long story!  where would i put location tag?

Comment: @Jan, not working...it is still redirecting to login page. I am using federatedAuthentication (STS)

Comment: @anilpurswani: Do you have an `[Authorize]` attribute on the action/controller?

Answer (score 2):

you are better off using attributes on your controllers and/or controller actions than specifying authorization in config.  [Authorize] for the actions you want limited to authenticated users and then the ones without the attribute are publicly available.

Comment: thanks. so do put <authentication mode="none"> in the web.config?

Comment: leave your authentication node as it is.  you still want your authentication to work the same as before.  just remove the authorization node.